# Cython program (print Hello world) much slower than pure Python

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am new to Cython. I've written a super simple test programm to access benefits of Cython. Yet, my pure python is alot faster. Am I doing something wrong?
test.py:

```
import timeit
imp = '''
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
from hello_cy import hello_c
from hello_py import hello_p
'''

code_py = '''
hello_p()
'''

code_cy = '''
hello_c()
'''

print(timeit.timeit(stmt=code_py, setup=imp))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=code_cy, setup=imp))
```

hello_py.py:

```
def hello_p():
    print('Hello World')
```

hello_cy.pyx:

```
from libc.stdio cimport printf

cpdef void hello_c():
    cdef char * hello_world = 'hello from C world'
    printf(hello_world)
```

**hello_py timeit takes 14.697s**

**hello_cy timeit takes 98s**

Am I missing something? How can I make my calls to cpdef functions run faster?

Thank you very much!

Comment: In the Cython example, the string is created on every call. In pure Python, it is a constant. Move cdef outside of the function and check again

Comment: Practically it'll be a C string literal so it shouldn't matter either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect a problem in your configuration.

I have (partially) reproduced your tests in Windows 10, Python 3.10.0, Cython 0.29.26, MSVC 2022, and got quite different results

Because in my tests the Cython code is slightly faster. I made 2 changes:

- in hello_cy.pyx, to make both code closer, I have added the newline:

  ```
    ...
    printf("%s\n", hello_world)
  ```
- In the main script I have splitted the call of the functions and the display of the times:

  ```
    ...
    pyp = timeit.timeit(stmt=code_py, setup=imp)
    pyc = timeit.timeit(stmt=code_cy, setup=imp)

    print(pyp)
    print(pyc)
  ```

When I run the script I get (after pages of hello...):

```
...
hello from C world
hello from C world
19.135732599999756
14.712803700007498
```

Which looks more like what could be expected...

Anyway, we do not really know what is tested here, because as much as possible, the IO should not be tested because it depends of a lot of things outside of the programs themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your responce. After playing around abit using your suggestion I got similar results.

Answer (score 0):

It just isn't a meaningful test - the two functions aren't the same:

- Python `print` prints a string followed by a newline. I think it then flushes the output.
- `printf` scans the string for formatting characters (e.g. `%s`) and then prints it without an extra newline. By default `printf` is line bufferred (i.e. flushes after each new line). Since you never post a new line or flush it, then it may be slowed down by managing an increasingly huge buffer.

In summary, don't be mislead by fairly meaningless microbenchmarks. Especially for terminal IO which is rarely actually a limiting factor.

Answer (score -1):

It takes too long because pyximport compiles the cython code on the fly (so you are measuring also compilation from cython to C and compilation C code to native library). You should measure calling already compiled code - see https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html#building-a-cython-module-using-setuptools

Comment: Thank you! This is what I suspected. Why is Cython -> binary compilation pretty slow?

Comment: I don't think this answer is right (assuming that the code that OP posted is actually what they ran). The complication happens during the "setup" stage of timeit, which isn't timed